# Ad not showing in iOS | React Native

Tags: react-native

I have followed all the steps in AD-Mob and Google-AD-Mob and set up everything but no matter what ad is not showing on the physical iOS device. Basically both packages are same, the later one is a forked one and maintained. I wasn't getting the ad in the simulator too, but for the past few days, I'm seeing ads in the simulator. everything is working fine on the android side. I'm calling a function to show an ad and the code for it is as follows.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    AdMobRewarded.setAdUnitID(this.rewardID);
    AdMobRewarded.setTestDevices([AdMobInterstitial.simulatorId]);

    AdMobRewarded.addEventListener('rewarded', (reward) => {

    /*this function will reward the user for seeing ads*/

      this.addTickets('ads');

    });
    AdMobRewarded.addEventListener('adLoaded', () =>
      console.log('AdMobRewarded => adLoaded'),
    );
    AdMobRewarded.addEventListener('adFailedToLoad', (error) =>
      console.warn(error),
    );
    AdMobRewarded.addEventListener('adOpened', () =>
      console.log('AdMobRewarded => adOpened'),
    );
    AdMobRewarded.addEventListener('videoStarted', () =>
      console.log('AdMobRewarded => videoStarted'),
    );
    AdMobRewarded.addEventListener('adClosed', () => {
      console.log('AdMobRewarded => adClosed');
      AdMobRewarded.requestAd().catch((error) => {});
    });
    AdMobRewarded.addEventListener('adLeftApplication', () =>
      console.log('AdMobRewarded => adLeftApplication'),
    );
    AdMobRewarded.requestAd().catch((error) => {});
}
```

```
    AdMobRewarded.showAd().catch((error) => {
      Toast.show('Ad is not ready, Please try after sometime.');
    });
```

Package versions

```
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
```

AD-Mob - https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob
Google-AD-Mob - https://github.com/thecodrr/react-native-google-admob

do I need to start a campaign in Google Ad-Mob for ads to show on the iOS device?
it would be very grateful if someone helps me with this

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps.

For iOS < 14.0, there was a `Limit Ad Tracking` option available. Turning it off should allow test ads or ads to be displaying using `react-native-admob@2.0.0-beta.6`.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: you can do a search under `Settings`. Just to reiterate, for iOS > 14.0, this option is not available.